# I can add a string literal to my table but if I pass a string as a variable it only works with numbers

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple mysql table [image]

This is the code to connect to database and insert into testtable:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testtable
     VALUES (NULL, $forename)";

    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    if($res === TRUE) {
        echo "data successfully inserted.";
    } else {
        printf("Could not insert data: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

In this case I try to insert `$forename` into my table.  If I use a string literal like `'Jim'` or `'123'` it gets inserted.  If `$forename` is given the value `123` or any other number it gets inserted.  If `$forename = 'Jim'` I get an error telling me there is no column `'Jim'` as though I were specifying a column in the table.

Comment: use a prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has happened to me before, you are missing quotes in the query. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ('{$forename}')";
```

Answer (score 2):

When forename is 'Jim', the query expands to ".... VALUES(NULL, Jim)", but you want "... VALUES(NULL, 'Jim')". Your query should read "...VALUES(NULL, 'Jim')".

Answer (score 1):

use a prepared statement

```
$db= mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (testfield)  VALUES (?)";

        if ($statement =$db->prepare($sql)){

        $statement->bind_param("s",$forename);
        msqi_stmt_execute($statement);
        };
```

Comment: I get errors with this the first was about that unbalanced ) I took it out but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Since your `id` field is an autonumber, you don't need to insert anything. You should also really get in the habit of specifying the columns to insert into:

Instead of :

```
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (NULL, $forename)
```

use:

```
INSERT INTO testtable 
(
    `testfield`
)
VALUES 
(
    '$forename'
)
```

Note that the "quotes" around the field name are back-ticks, not single quotes.

Of course, using string insertion like this is a security risk, so you really should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as case1352 demonstrates in his answer.

Comment: I had high hopes I was sure the back-ticks would do it but same 'Unknown column 'Jim' comes up.

Comment: The field name uses back-ticks; the value uses single quotes. That should work as-is. Try to `echo $sql` somewhere on the view so that you can see what you are actually sending to MySQL.